# Custom routing Sonata

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I'm working on a small project and for that I need a CMS. After some searching I found Sonata CMS, that is build on top of Symfony2. It's running quite good, and must say that it is a nice bundle.

But now i'n running in to a small issue. I've installed a few prefixed bundles like PageBundle, NotificationBundle, etc. Those bundle's work fine, but I would like to change the url they use.

For example the PageBundle uses myurl.com/admin/sonata/page/page/tree

It should be possible to change it if i read [the documentation](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-2/doc/reference/routing.html#create-a-route) here. But the difference with the examples given in the documentation is that the pre-installed bundles are for a great part located in the vendor folder.

Somewhere I have to add:
`protected $baseRouteName = 'your_name'; protected $baseRoutePattern = 'your_name';` but i can't find out were.

Does anyone have any experience with altering the cms url's to a custom route?

Answer (score 0):

To override the routes of an admin just override $baseRoutePattern in your admin class:

```
class VarietyAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
    protected $baseRouteName = 'admin_libio_variety';
    protected $baseRoutePattern = 'libio/variety';
}
```

https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/routing.html#route-patterns-urls

for the bundles other than the AdminBundle you can simply copy the routing files from the bundle to your own, customize the routes and import this file in your config instead of the vendor one.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/override.html#routing